# How to enable save passwords using selenium chromedriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, passwords

when I start chromedriver by default password save options are disabled (I can see options to save password are enabled in chrome config), but when I log in any website, chromedriver never ask me to save the password.
For my tests I need to save passwords, I have tried some options but nothing works.
I used same profile to open chromedriver, so I don't use the temporary profiles that chromedriver creates every time I launch it.
(sorry about my english)

Comment: _I used same profile to open chromedriver_: What is the issue with this approach?

Answer (score 1):

**Selenium Java**

```
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", true);
prefs.put("profile.password_manager_enabled", true);

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

**Selenium Python**

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddUserProfilePreference("credentials_enable_service", true);
options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.password_manager_enabled", true);
var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: You have suggested `put("profile.password_manager_enabled", false)` but OP needs _For my tests I need to save passwords_

Comment: thanks @DebanjanB, I was on automatic there, I ensure it is disabled. Thanks for the QA and eyeballing, have corrected above